# Changing a store-bought LED power supply's output

Tags: power-supply, led-driver

I bought a flat panel LED light including a LED driver. I want to permanently dim the light a bit, without having to buy their expensive variable dimmer.

I tried to make a diagram of this power supply. I hope it is without faults. I have no experience with this kind of PSU, as I am only at a hobby level.

Is it possible to lower the output of this PSU without too much hassle?

[image: http://www.djelle.dk/temp/PSU_circuit_for_flat_panel_LED.jpg]

- L2: Drawn wrong. Turn 90° in diagram.
- VR1: HEL 7D471K (Varistor)
- CX1: HMKP-X2 0.15 μF 250V~275V~305V~310V~
- CB1: MB10F MJ (Passivated bridge rectifier)
- R5:  Unknown SMD
- CY1: JEC JD222MY (High voltage ceramic capacitor)
- CY2: JEC JD222MY (High voltage ceramic capacitor)
- D2:  ES3J (3A Super fast recovery rectifier diode)
- U1:  7 pin DIP - M13W71 OB5682T (power management IC?)
  (It was covered by a heat sink with paste.)
  [image: Photo of IC top markings]
- LED strip on output: About 50-100 LEDs.

PSU Declaration:

- Input: 220-240V~ 50/60Hz 0.17A PF: 0.5
- Output: DC30-42V 600mA No Load: 50V Max.
- Output Power: 25W

Comment: It's a constant current supply. Can you put an extra load in parallel so there is less current to LEDs?

Comment: You need to rotate L2 by 90 degrees in your schematic. It's a filter, but a transformer.

Comment: A datasheet on U1 would give an answer to your question. My google-fu is however failing me. Could any of the zeros be an O, or an 8 be an B perchance? Photo of the markings?

Comment: @winny Yes I did take a photo before closing up. http://www.djelle.dk/temp/U1.jpg

Comment: The reason for me putting a zero is that I was sure I saw a dot in it's center. I guess not. As it IS an OB5682T for which there is a datasheet. Thanks for pointing this out. https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/On-Bright-Elec-OB5282CPA_C131099.pdf

Comment: What type are the LED strips that may be connected to output - haven't seen *voltage fed* ones in the range stated, and 50 LEDs in series emitting at 42 V would be infrared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PWM controller is On-Bright OB5682TASP

Product page:
https://www.on-bright.com/en/index/product/detail/cid/59/id/215.shtml

Datasheet:
https://file.elecfans.com/web2/M00/4E/E3/pYYBAGK9T4KAew0NABTgOtAgdSA590.pdf

[image]
Image borrowed from manufacturer's page.

[image]
The manufacturer uses non-standard pinout numbering. I would call CS pin 8, the leftmost one on top row in your image.
Resistor to CS pin will set output current via this formula:

[image]

Vth_ocp is 500 mV but N is unknown unless you unwind the transformer. But nevermind, **just increase R3 and/or R4 (designator from OPs schematic) and your output current will decrease**.

Thanks to Spehro Pefhany for pointing out the parallel connection between R3 and R4.

Comment: Good find +1. \$I_{LED}\$ is proportional to 1/(R3||R4).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Oh! There is a tiny tiny dot between R3 and R4. I didn't see it when you mentioned R3 above.

Comment: Followup: I tried to remove R3  (1.3 ohm) which made the LEDs go 100% dark. Which to me indicate I would need a very specific low ohm resistor, which I don't have. So I gave up and put the resistor back in, and it was back to normal. Thanks all for ur help and advice.

Comment: @Djelle What do you have? You can cheat and place several 10 ohm in parallel by stacking them.

Comment: That is true. But I would need 8+ (10 ohm) in parallel to get to where I need. And that is a bit of overkill imo. Also been thinking of using resister wire or a potentiometer. Meybe I'll try it later. Thx.

Comment: @Djelle That or order resistors.

Answer (score 3):

I would try removing one of R3, R4. If that works and it's not enough dimming, put the two in series.

A bit of a guess here, if it gets ruined...

Answer (score 2):

U1 most probably is a PWM Controller with built-in MOSFET. Looking at the schematic, it looks like R2 sets the duty cycle but confirm it with its datasheet to be clear.

Comment: Thanks for the answers all. I could determine that I do need the data sheet for U1. So I managed to get it's designation which is M13W71 0B5682T. And a 3rd line with "Pb" or "Pa" maybe. But a search revealed no hits for such a component. So unless somebody can recognise this component, I would have to try either of the two suggestions. Not sure if I want to risk it yet.